# Subscribe BLE Characteristics UUID in Pygatt or bgapi

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluegiga

When communicating with BLE peripherals,
Compiled toolkit (i.e. LightBlue) successfully connects to device and subscribes service uuid or characteristics uuid. 
Since the target device uses 4 characters uuid, (i.e. 3EA0), pygatt and bgapi repeatedly show error message like below.

```
WARNING:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:UUID 3ea3 is of unknown type
WARNING:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:UUID 3ea6 is of unknown type
WARNING:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:UUID 3e71 is of unknown type
```

Based on the community thread from another developer,
http://www.cypress.com/forum/proc-ble/pygatt-and-cypress-ble-dongle

It seems pygatt or bgapi blocks 4-characters uuid at some point.

Anybody succeed to subscribe 4-character uuid with BLED112 dongle using pygatt or bgapi?

Comment: I have the same problem - did this work for you?

Comment: No I am still working on it.  I think pygatt is not fully integrated with bgapi now, and I found some TODO in pygatt codes.

Comment: Okay - thanks for the update.

Comment: PhilBot, the function was blocked by the developer to prevent the confusion with pre-reserved UUIDs. If you check the most recent code of pygatt, it is modified to allow 4char UUIDs

Comment: Hi iPsych, i am trying to subscribe to a characteristic, but am unable to do so.  Here is my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888220/pygatt-unable-to-execute-device-subscribe . Can you please share your solution?